# Error in R. Error in gsub("(?<=\n)(?=.|\n)", continue, x, perl = TRUE) :

Tags: r

I am encountering an error in R that I cannot seem to figure out. I am creating an R markdown document where I read in an a csv table using this code.

```
iati <- read.csv(file="/filepath/IATI_NGOS.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
```

and then using ggplot2 I create a plot using the following code.

```
figure_one <- ggplot(iati, aes(iati$reporting.org))+
              geom_bar(fill="blue")+
              ylab("Total Activities")+
              xlab("NGO Reporting Organizations in IATI")+
              ggtitle("Total Number of Activities compared to each NGO Reporting Organization in IATI")+
              coord_flip()
```

When I try to call figure_one in the R markdown I get the following error:

```
Quitting from lines 44-55 (NGO_IATI.Rmd) 
Error in gsub("(?<=\n)(?=.|\n)", continue, x, perl = TRUE) : 
input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
Calls: <Anonymous> ... paste -> comment_out -> line_prompt -> paste -> gsub
In addition: Warning message:
In grep("\n", message) : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
Execution halted
```

When I run this code in a regular R script I have absolutely no issues. I have search for some answers but can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks a locale issue. Can you show a reproducible example and session info?

Comment: It must be a local issue because every time I run that code and then call figure_one in the r code blocks of the markdown document I get the error I posted. What would be helpful for a reproducible example because it occurs every time for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended solving my issue by just doing a fresh install of R and Rstudio on my local machine. I think the recent update to Yosemite on my local environment created a lot of issues with the TeX plugin I had installed for R markdown.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same question when I knit my rmarkdown document and find **encoding is the cause.
When you use functions like `read.csv`, `fread` or `read_csv`, you will read the column name.

1. If column names are in other languages, like Chinese, the problem will easily happen.
2. Or you rmarkdown works on Windows, but the encoding bug happens on Mac, a different environment.

The temporal solution is to rename the column name in English and resave the data files.

Here is the pseudocode in R to show my idea.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
fread('yourfile.csv',encoding = 'UTF-8') %>% 
    purrr::set_names(c('x1','x2','x3')) %>% 
    write_excel_csv('yourfile_2.csv')
```

Here the new file `yourfile_2.csv` is fine to rmarkdown knit without encoding problems happening.